# What is the output, if we use a "character pointer" as an index to a character array in C++ and how to achieve this in c SHarp?

Tags: c#, visual-c++

I have a VC++ character array **"wchar_t arr[0x30] = { 0x0,0x1,..., 0xC...hexadecimal initialization here ......}**". There is one more C++ character pointer **wchar_t * xyz**.
  An operation something like----         **wchar_t ch = arr[xyz[2]]**  is done.
Can someone kindly explain in detail what is happening in this, because arr[] is a char array and we should pass an integer as an index to any array right? But here the index passed to the character array "arr[] "  is another character pointer xyz[2].  **In the above code suppose a character 'a' is stored at xyz[2]** than does it mean we are indexing a C++ character array like this---   **arr[xyz[2]] becomes arr['a'].** Kindly let me know. 
 How can I achieve this in c SHarp..  Probably if I get to know that what is happening in C++ code above I can myself achieve it in C SHarp. Can anyone kindly let me know what is happening here in this C++ code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens is that the `wchar_t` stored at `xyz[2]` is [promoted](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_conversion#Type_promotion_in_C-like_languages) to an `int`, then used as an index into the `arr` array.

It also means that, if `xyz[2]` contains `L'a'`, the program will exhibit [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239938/c-accesses-an-array-out-of-bounds-gives-no-error-why), since `arr` only has space for `48` items but `L'a'` will be promoted to `97`.

Concerning the second part of your question, C# [only supports](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_%28computing%29#C.23) pointer arithmetic inside [`unsafe`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t2yzs44b.aspx) blocks, so you'll probably want to use arrays instead:

```
char[] arr = new char[0x30];
char[] xyz = Something();
char ch = arr[xyz[2]];
```

Comment: Thank you very much for such a speedy answer.